# multiply two columns (delimited) using Bash

Tags: awk, terminal

I'm very basic with awk, so please help me with this. I have three columns that look like:

```
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.333333
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.333333
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.333333
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_122 1
```

What I want to do is to multiply the values (after `x`) in the first column with the numbers in the third column and print in a different column. So the output should look like:

```
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_122 1 20463
```

I tried this but it puts 0 in the first column:
`cat file.csv | awk '{split($1,arr,"_");$1=arr[2] * $3 }1'`

Comment: If you print out `arr[2]` you'll see an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `x` instead.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.6f"} {split($1,arr,"x");print $0,arr[2]*$3}' file
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.333333 9935.656731
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_122 1 20463
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about it. Thanks :)

Comment: With oguz ismail's idea to use OFMT: `awk '{print $0,$2*$4}' FS='[x ]' OFMT='%.6f' file`

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the string functions `match()` to get the location of `x` in field-1 and then `substr()` to extract the number beginning after the `'x'` and save it in a variable (`n`). Then just output the entire record and add the additional field calculated by `n * $3`. For example:

```
awk '{n = substr($1, match($1, /x/) + 1); print $0, n * $3}' file
```

The [String Manipulations](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) reference is a good place for information on each of the functions.

**Example Output**

```
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.333333 9935.66
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.333333 9935.66
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.333333 9935.66
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_122 1 20463
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: nice, on a similar vein with GNU awk, `awk -v FPAT='([0-9]+\\.)?[0-9]+' '{print $0, $1 * $NF}'`